# How to do multiple select and then concat data together in mysql

Tags: mysql

Am trying to retrieve data from 3 tables at once but i am not sure how to do it in mysql (to be truthful i am really bad at database stuff so this confuse the hell out me).

```
1st logins table that has 3 columns id, email, password
2nd users table that has 4 columns id, name, surname, location_id
3rd locations has 3 columns location_id, country, city
```

what i want to do is write query using the users id to get the email from the logins table, then get name and surname from the users table. I then want to use the location_id i got from the users table to find out what city he or she is from.

i hope that makes sense to you and thanks for your time.

Comment: @Shadow thanks for the help

Answer (score -1, accepted):

maybe this could be helpful

```
select a.email, B.name, B.surname, C.city
from logings A join users B on (A.id=B.id) join locations C on
```

Comment: shadow pointed me to the correct post, thanks for the help by the way